# Skip events on sp_BlitzIndex

Tags: sql-server, index, sp-blitzindex

Is there any way to skip some results on sp_BlitzIndex? Like has done on sp_Blitz, using the @SkipChecksTable.

For example, i have some index thats are not in use, but, those indexes are UNIQUE and i cannot drop then. I just want to ignore these indexes in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no functionality like that in sp_BlitzIndex.